# Why does cleaned_data give a list encoding as a string?

Tags: django

I've got a field defined like this:

```
service_types = CharField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=ServiceTypes), initial=[ServiceTypes.OPEN_TRANS])
```

I want to "clean" it to return a single integer (the choices are encoded as power-of-2 flags):

```
def clean_service_types(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['service_types']
    return sum(map(int, data))
```

But it throws me an error, "cannot convert `[` to int". turns out `data` is:

```
u"[u'1', u'4', u'32']"
```

...oh, just occured to me that this is probably because it's a `CharField`. However, when I change it to a `MultipleChoiceField` nothing gets rendered. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. Have to move the `choices` out of the widget constructor:

```
MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=ServiceTypes, initial=[ServiceTypes.OPEN_TRANS])
```

I'll leave this question here in case any one else is scratching their head.